# How to define the AccessibleTableInfo in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I have the following structure in C++. I would like to define it in C#. How to do that. Anyone have some thoughts

```
    typedef struct AccessibleTableInfoTag {
JOBJECT64 caption;  // AccesibleContext
JOBJECT64 summary;  // AccessibleContext
jint rowCount;
jint columnCount;
JOBJECT64 accessibleContext;
JOBJECT64 accessibleTable;
} AccessibleTableInfo;
```

I tried it the following way to convert the AccessibleTableInfo tag in C#. But it does not work.

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct AccessibleTableInfo
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string caption; 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string summary; 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int rowCount;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int columnCount;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
        public AccessibleContextInfo accessibleContext;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
        public AccessibleContextInfo accessibleTable;

    }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct AccessibleContextInfo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1024)]
    public string name; // the AccessibleName of the object
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1024)]
    public string description; // the AccessibleDescription of the object

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string role; // localized AccesibleRole string
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string role_en_US; // AccesibleRole string in the en_US locale
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string states; // localized AccesibleStateSet string (comma separated)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string states_en_US; // AccesibleStateSet string in the en_US locale (comma separated)

    public Int32 indexInParent; // index of object in parent
    public Int32 childrenCount; // # of children, if any

    public Int32 x; // screen coords in pixels
    public Int32 y; // "
    public Int32 width; // pixel width of object
    public Int32 height; // pixel height of object

    public Boolean accessibleComponent; // flags for various additional
    public Boolean accessibleAction; // Java Accessibility interfaces
    public Boolean accessibleSelection; // FALSE if this object doesn't
    public Boolean accessibleText; // implement the additional interface
    // in question

    // BOOL accessibleValue; // old BOOL indicating whether AccessibleValue is supported
    public Boolean accessibleInterfaces; // new bitfield containing additional interface flags

}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the following way

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct AccessibleTable
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int index;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int row;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int column;

}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct AccessibleTableInfo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst=2)]
    public string caption;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst=2)]
    public string summary;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int rowCount;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int columnCount;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    public AccessibleContextInfo[] accessibleContext;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    public AccessibleTable[] accessibleTable;
}
```